# Filtering top-level categories in hierarchical Pandas Dataframe using lower-level data

Tags: python, pandas, hierarchical-data

I have a Pandas DataFrame that contains a large number of categories that each have features and each of those have their own subfeatures that are grouped into pairs. A simple version looks like the following:

```
                                        0         1    ...
categories features subfeatures                    
cat1       feature1 subfeature1 -0.224487 -0.227524
                    subfeature2 -0.591399 -0.799228
           feature2 subfeature1  1.190110 -1.365895    ...
                    subfeature2  0.720956 -1.325562
cat2       feature1 subfeature1  1.856932       NaN
                    subfeature2 -1.354258 -0.740473
           feature2 subfeature1  0.234075 -1.362235    ...
                    subfeature2  0.013875  1.309564
cat3       feature1 subfeature1       NaN       NaN
                    subfeature2 -1.260408  1.559721    ...
           feature2 subfeature1  0.419246  0.084386
                    subfeature2  0.969270  1.493417

...                    ...               ...
```

It can be generated using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(seed=90)
results = np.random.randn(3,2,2,2)
results[2,0,0,:] = np.nan
results[1,0,0,1] = np.nan
results = results.reshape((-1,2))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["cat1", "cat2", "cat3"],
                                    ["feature1", "feature2"], 
                                    ["subfeature1", "subfeature2"]], 
                                   names=["categories", "features", "subfeatures"])
df = pd.DataFrame(results, index=index)
```

**Now I would like to retrieve top-level categories (`cat1` etc) that have a difference between `subfeature1` and `subfeature2` in the same column (`0` or `1`) that is above a certain threshold.**

For example: if the threshold is 1 then I would expect `cat2` and `cat3` to be returned because the difference between `subfeature1` and `subfeature2` in column `0` is 1.856932 - (-1.354258), which is 3.21119 > threshold = 1 for `feature1` in `cat2`. Similarly, the difference between `subfeature1` and `subfeature2` in column `1` in `cat3`, `feature2` is 1.493417 - 0.084386 = 1.409031 > 1. On the other hand, `cat1` would not be returned because none the differences between subfeature pairs are greater than 1. `NaN` values would invalidate a pair and be ignored.

#### What I have tried

I have managed to implement an iterative approach, but I feel like I am not taking advantage of Pandas' full capabilities and its performance is lacking:

```
for cat in df.index.levels[0]:
    for feature in df.index.levels[1]:
        df2 = df.xs((cat, feature))
        diffs = abs(df2.loc['subfeature1'] - df2.loc['subfeature2'])
        if max(diffs) > threshold and cat not in results:
            results.append(cat)
```

yielding:

```
['cat2', 'cat3']
```

How could I go about implementing something like this using Pandas' built-in vectorized abilities?

**EDIT: Using Jeff's answer below, I noticed something funky:**

```
def f(x):
    a = max(abs(x.xs('subfeature1',level='subfeatures')-x.xs('subfeature2',level='subfeatures')))
    print a
    return a > 1

result = df.groupby(level=['categories','features']).filter(f)
print(result)
```

gives:

```
0.366912262765
0.571703714569
1
0.469153603312
0.0403331129905
3.2111900125 <------------------------------------------------
nan
0.220200012413
2.67179897269  <---------------------------------------------------
nan
nan
0.550023734074
1.40903094796  <-----------------------------------------------------!!!!!!!!!!!
                                        0         1
categories features subfeatures                    
cat2       feature1 subfeature1  1.856932       NaN
                    subfeature2 -1.354258 -0.740473
```

I've highlighted all the places where the algorithm should include a category based on the score. Yet, it doesn't for `cat3`. Could the nans have something to do with it?

Comment: Use boolean indexing along with the multi-indexer slicers (see down a bit in the example); you need 0.14.0: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#multiindexing-using-slicers

Comment: How would you suggest that I use the multi-indexer slicers in this instance? Would I still have to iterate through all the categories? I feel like I might be able to do everything in one line using this, but I'm not sure exactly how. The examples on that page are helpful, but none of the cases match mine when I scanned them.

Answer (score 1):

Groupby the top-2 levels. Then use a filter to only return the max difference of the features you want (threshold here is 0)

```
In [41]: df.groupby(level=['categories','features']).filter(lambda x: (x.xs('subfeature1',level='subfeatures')-x.xs('subfeature2',level='subfeatures')).max()>0)
Out[41]: 
                                        0         1
categories features subfeatures                    
cat1       feature1 subfeature1 -0.224487 -0.227524
                    subfeature2 -0.591399 -0.799228
           feature2 subfeature1  1.190110 -1.365895
                    subfeature2  0.720956 -1.325562
cat2       feature1 subfeature1  1.856932       NaN
                    subfeature2 -1.354258 -0.740473
           feature2 subfeature1  0.234075 -1.362235
                    subfeature2  0.013875  1.309564
```

A useful debugging aid to to do something like this:

```
def f(x):
    print x
    return (x.xs(......)) # e.g. the filter from above

df.groupby(.....).filter(f)
```

Comment: If set the threshold to 1 and take the abs value like so: `df.groupby(level=['categories','features']).filter(lambda x: max(abs(x.xs('subfeature1',level='subfeatures')-x.xs('subfeature2',level='subfeatures')))>1)`. I'm not getting `cat3` like I expect? The code makes sense.

Comment: I added an easy way to debug this

Comment: it also appears as though filter returns a subset of the original DataFrame, how would I get only the categories like `cat1` and `cat2`?

Comment: Thanks for the help! But, it seems like there's an issue. I edited my original post with the helpful debug code that you gave. `cat3` should clearly kept in, but it is being filtered out.

Comment: the result of the ``.xs`` subtractions is a Series, so you need to use pandas operations their (you are prob not returning a scalar, but an array)

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference because the `a` variable from the edited version above is already the correct value and the function `f` returns true for 2 locations within `cat2` and the one for `cat3` so both should show up in the final answer. I double checked with `a = (xs stuff).abs().max() > 1` and `cat3` still doesn't show up.